# appengine connected to many datastores

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on a project with App Engine flex in node.js env. The App Engine hosts a simple restapi in node.js that retrieves data from Cloud Datastore. 
My problem is that I have to separate the data per country, and a country should not be able to access data from another country.
I've tried separating the data per namespace, but it´s still accessible to everyone. 
Is it possible to have many Datastores connected to one App Engine? Or do I have to create a separate project for every country? 
That would be a maintenance nightmare and expensive. Anyone know of a solution?
Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

GAE doesn't support multitenancy for Node.js yet. If your project just hosts a simple Rest API, use another language, like [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/multitenancy/multitenancy#Python_Avoiding_data_leaks), [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/multitenancy/multitenancy#Java_Avoiding_data_leaks) or [Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/multitenancy/multitenancy#Go_Avoiding_data_leaks)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the other languages that are namespace-enabled.

Comment: I've read up on multitenancy  [GAE multitenancy](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/multitenancy)  and it's still not clear to me if I can restrict access between the different namespaces. The best would be to set IAM roles to a specific namespace, but that seems impossible. The docs says:  "Namespaces are not a security mechanism in Cloud Datastore. A user with access to one partition in a project has access to all partitions in the project. Namespaces provide a way to organize your entities within a project."

Comment: As stated in the document, for now this is not possible. There are however opened feature requests for [Restricting access to a Specific Kind in Datastore](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78778579) and support of [Cloud IAM roles per namespace](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38467767)